# Allow Chrome extension text to be read by screenreader

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my chrome extension 508 compliant for screenreader accessibility. My extension is a tutorial extension which displays text for each step in the tutorial. In my case this means that a screenreader such as ChromeVox needs to be able to read the text displayed for each step. Is there a way to do this and integrate it into my extension?

Comment: It is worth noting (I didn't know) that ChromeVox is a Chrome extension. For other readers: a significant part of what this question is asking is *how can my Chrome extension allow another Chrome extension (such as ChromeVox screen reader) to read and modify it*? (Or, is there another workaround?)

Comment: Thanks. It appears that ChromeVox is able to read the text in my extension at the end.